# Pygame screen.blit() from not zero y coordinate

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw on screen grass in specific level [y], below those i want only dirt to show up. This is almost all my code, deleted is only unrelated stuff

```py
import pygame
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
height_of_grass = 150
run = True
speed_of_player = 1

player = pygame.image.load("images/steve.png")
grass = pygame.image.load("images/grass_block.jpg")
dirt = pygame.image.load("images/dirt_block.jpg")
sky = pygame.image.load("images/sky.png")
clouds = pygame.image.load("images/cloud.png")
oak_wood_log = pygame.image.load("images/oak_wood_log.png")
oak_leaves = pygame.image.load("images/oak_leaves.png")

keys = [False, False, False, False]
player_position = [100, 100]

while run:
    screen.fill((50, 168, 158))


    screen.blit(player, player_position)
    for x in range(int(width/grass.get_width()) + 1):
        screen.blit(grass, (x*grass.get_width(), height_of_grass))
    x = 0
    for x in range(int(width/dirt.get_width()) + 1):
        for y in range(height_of_grass, int(height / grass.get_height()) + 1):
           screen.blit(dirt, (x*dirt.get_width, y*dirt.get_height))
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    if player_position[0] < -16 or player_position[0] > (width + 16) or player_position[1] < -16 or player_position[1] > (height + 16):
        print("You´ve broke the game! Congratilations")
        exit(-1)
```

it is only part of code which i have problem with. My pygame window is just not showing dirt bellow.

Comment: My question is still same: code is not showing dirt bellow the grass. Thansk for debuging closing sequence.

Comment: It has to  `if event.type == pygame.QUIT` rather than `if event == pygame.QUIT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dirt is not show, because the range of the inner loop is wrong and the y location of the dirt tiles is not proper calculated.

Calculate the y level where the dirt starts and the height of the area which has to be covered by the dirt:

```
dirt_start_height = height_of_grass + grass.get_width()
all_dirt_height = height - dirt_start_height
```

Use `dirt_start_height` and `all_dirt_height` in the nested loops which draw the dirt:

```
while run:

    # [...]

    dirt_start_height = height_of_grass + grass.get_width()
    all_dirt_height = height - dirt_start_height
    for x in range(int(width/dirt.get_width()) + 1):
        for y in range(int(all_dirt_height / grass.get_height()) + 1):
           screen.blit(dirt, (x*dirt.get_width(), dirt_start_height + y*dirt.get_height()))
```

Comment: I already had pygame.flip.display.flip() called later, but i´ve put it right after this code and still nothing.

Comment: This is my first python game and first bigger project, I don´t know what handling is. 
Program is showing grass and player okay, but that dirt...

Comment: You´ve made my game run smoother, thanks for that. I have event handling, but it is not working: 
`
while run:
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event == pygame.QUIT:
run = False`

Comment: @mkoo7mk I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your "dirt drawing loop", you're looking at `grass.get_height()`

```
for x in range(int(width/dirt.get_width()) + 1):
    for y in range(height_of_grass, int(height / grass.get_height()) + 1):
        screen.blit(dirt, (x*dirt.get_width(), y*dirt.get_height()))
```

I think you meant to put `dirt.get_height` there instead.

Comment: Didn´t help. in my "grass drawing loop" i am using grass.get_width() and it is working fine

Comment: Probably `dirt` is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) object, in this case 
[`get_height()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_height()) is correct.